# Vue.js with Anime.js animating buttons

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, anime.js

I have styled some button and want to animate them in a Vue component using Anime.js.

```js
<div class="links">
   <a 
    class="button green" 
    href="#" 
    target="_blank"
    @mouseover="bouncyButtonEnter"
    @mouseout="bouncyButtonLeave">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60">
     <path ref="buttonPath" d="M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z"/>
    </svg>
    <span ref="buttonSpan">CodePen</span>
   </a>
   <a 
    class="button blue" 
    href="#" 
    target="_blank"
    @mouseover="bouncyButtonEnter"
    @mouseout="bouncyButtonLeave">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60">
     <path ref="buttonPath" d="M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z"/>
    </svg>
    <span ref="buttonSpan">Github</span>
   </a>
   <a 
    class="button red"
    href="#" 
    target="_blank"
    @mouseover="bouncyButtonEnter"
    @mouseout="bouncyButtonLeave">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 180 60">
     <path ref="buttonPath" d="M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z"/>
    </svg>
    <span ref="buttonSpan">Contact</span>
   </a>
  </div>
```

```js
<script>
import anime from "animejs";

export default {
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    bouncyButtonEnter: function() {
      anime.remove([this.$refs.buttonPath, this.$refs.buttonSpan]);
      anime({
        targets: this.$refs.buttonPath,
        d:
          "M10,10 C10,10 50,7 90,7 C130,7 170,10 170,10 C170,10 172,20 172,30 C172,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,53 90,53 C50,53 10,50 10,50 C10,50 8,40 8,30 C8,20 10,10 10,10 Z",
        elasticity: 700,
        offset: 0
      });
      anime({
        targets: this.$refs.buttonSpan,
        scale: 1.15,
        duration: 800,
        offset: 0
      });
    },
    bouncyButtonLeave: function() {
      anime.remove([this.$refs.buttonPath, this.$refs.buttonSpan]);
      anime({
        targets: this.$refs.buttonPath,
        d:
          "M10,10 C10,10 50,9.98999977 90,9.98999977 C130,9.98999977 170,10 170,10 C170,10 170.009995,20 170.009995,30 C170.009995,40 170,50 170,50 C170,50 130,50.0099983 90,50.0099983 C50,50.0099983 10,50 10,50 C10,50 9.98999977,40 9.98999977,30 C9.98999977,20 10,10 10,10 Z",
        elasticity: 700,
        offset: 0
      });
      anime({
        targets: this.$refs.buttonSpan,
        scale: 1,
        duration: 800,
        offset: 0
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Im trying with the methods **bouncyButtonEnter** and **bouncyButtonLeave** using **Refs** to animate and it **works** as it should. My problem is that it only works for one button. How should I make it work so every button would animate ?

I also have a code on [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y4q4vzxv4)

Answer (score 1):

"ref" can only refrence one element. You can refrence your buttons with class. And use that class in anime.js target.  Something like `querySelector(".button-span")` and `querySelector(".button-path")` 
 will definitely work for all of them.

UPDATE: Ooh now i understand your need clearly. well to apply it only on the hovered button you can use the event.target to apply the animation on that element only. here is how your methods should look like.

```
methods: {
    bouncyButtonEnter: function(event) {
        anime.remove([this.$refs.buttonPath, this.$refs.buttonSpan]);
        anime({
            targets: event.target.querySelector("path"),
            ....

        });
        anime({
            targets: event.target.querySelector("span"),
            ...
        });
    },

    bouncyButtonLeave: function(event) {
        anime.remove([this.$refs.buttonPath, this.$refs.buttonSpan]);
        anime({
            targets: event.target.querySelector("path"),
            ....
        });
        anime({
            targets: event.target.querySelector("span"),
            ...
        });
    }  
}
```

Comment: I change from refs to classes and in my methods I call them with event.target but I end up with a small confusing problem. My path is animating but the span does not (span=null). Can you check my updated code ? https://codesandbox.io/s/1y4q4vzxv4